# Margin-top equal to window height

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if there is a way to set the top margin of a div equal to window height with javascript. When I set 100%, it uses width not the height.

Thank you.

Comment: write the code that you have tried

Comment: Are you using jQuery or vanilla javascript?

Answer (score 0):

```
var h = window.innerHeight;
document.getElementById("dd").setAttribute("style","margin-top:"+h+"px");
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="div" style="background: blue; width: 5pc; height: 5pc;">
</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById('div').style.marginTop = window.innerHeight + 'px/pc';
</script>
```

view the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h_awk/4hZzS/1/) here